# Are Spring Boot 2.6.10 and 3.1.5 completely different things?

Tags: spring-boot

First of all, let me disclose that I am new to Maven.

I have a Maven that works fine on version 2.6.10.

When I run it on 3.1.5, I get an error.

The error is that javax.xml.bind.annotation is missing.

In 2.6.10, I see that there is javax in tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar in External Libraries, but not in 3.1.5.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: SPring Boot 3.x is for JakartaEE anything prior to that is for JavaEE. Which sadly is a big thing due to changed namespaces of JavaEE related classes.

Comment: There is a guide to migrate your project from 2.7 to 3.0 that shows you the changes required for the migration: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/wiki/Spring-Boot-3.0-Migration-Guide